# Compatible way to use either :py OR :py3 in vim?

Tags: python, vim, python-3.x, ultisnips

In my `.vimrc` and my vim plugin UltiSnips I've got a lot of code that looks like that

```
:py << EOF
print("Hi")
EOF
```

Now, I want to check if python3 is compiled into Vim via `has("python3")` and then use `:py3` instead of `:py`. Keeping the python code compatible between python 2 and 3 is not the issue - the issue is to tell vim to use :py3 if is available and :py otherwise.

Has someone a good idea?

Comment: The obvious way would be to have a `if has("python3")` each time you want to use `:py3`.

Comment: Or maybe a wrapper function that takes the Python code you want to run as argument and executes a single `if`.

Comment: Your first comment is the obvious solution which I chose for now. The second comment is what I wanted to do but I know of no way to make a user defined function accept the heredoc (<< EOF) syntax. Do you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can take advantage on the fact that user defined commands in vim are simply place-in-patter-and-eval statements, and write:

```
if has("python3")
    command! -nargs=1 Py py3 <args>
else
    command! -nargs=1 Py py <args>
endif
```

Then you can use `:Py` to run python commands the same way as you regularly use `:py` or `:py3`.

Comment: No, this does not work with the << EOF syntax that the python command understands. However, it is slightly nicer than my let solution.

Comment: Works perfectly fine for me:
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/832/52433408.png/

Comment: Indeed... It works for me too. I must have done something wrong when I tried that myself. Maybe the -nargs=1 argument. Thanks for your persistence in helping me! I one-up your solution but I will still keep the one I mentioned below because it seems to be a bit obstrusive to define a new command for internal use only and because I have reports that exec solution works across various systems.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this now in an ugly fashion by only checking ONCE for python3 or python, then setting a variable

```
let g:_uspy=":py "   or ":py3 "
```

and then throwing the << EOF syntax overboard and instead call each line of python via

```
exec g:_uspy "print('Hello')"
```

which seems to work okaish. See the full solution in this git blob:

https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips/blob/da49b4b7c4669bc462a98c9abc71b42d43d408bc/plugin/UltiSnips.vim